# How to make Visual Studio Code automatically load required assets

Tags: visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have started using Visual Studio Code.

I did the following steps to create a new *.Net Core console* project:

- Opened a folder
- Started the Terminal
- Issued the command *dotnet new*
- Issued the command *dotnet restore*
- Hit F5

I always get a *Warn sign* about the missing assets:

[image]

I chose *Do not ask me again*, and it was a very bad idea *as it creates a template tasks.json and I have to manually replace the output path*.

Unfortunately, there is no option like *Do not ask me again and load the assets automatically*, so it seems I have to manually load whenever I create a new project.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: The C# extension is open source at GitHub. You should raise a feature request directly and discuss with the developers. Make no sense to post here.

Comment: @LexLi It makes sense if there is a feature but I didn't find it...it is code related and an emerging trend...so let the users decide if they know such a hidden (and fair) feature :)

Answer (score 13):

The Visual Studio Code C# extension can generate assets to build and debug for you. If you missed the prompt when you first opened a new C# project, you can still run this command by opening the Command Palette (**View > Command Palette**) and typing "**>.NET: Generate Assets for Build and Debug**". Selecting this will generate the .vscode, launch.json, and tasks.json configuration files that you need.

Source: https://github.com/dotnet/docs/pull/6456/files/0af542730e9b108964a09fe67b16d5bd70626fca#diff-1e85f61328dc43337b1fbf612b1b8b57dfdd8bb3768daf9004dcd9b4ae38f4b0

Comment: Thanks, but the whole point of _automatic_ loading is to avoid clicking or typing commands manually 

Answer (score 9):

**Edit**: this is not directly answering the real question but answering a similar question that linked me to here of "what do I do if I hit *'Don't ask me again*' by mistake.". Feel free to downvote :-)

It's crappy, but you CAN get around the disappearance of the prompt by manually deleting a flag.

From the command palette, "toggle developer tools"

From there, look go to the "application tab" and look at "file" under "local storage"

[image]

Scroll through the list until you find the "workspace" row that points to the workspace you need. You'll find a json blob that looks similar to this.

[image]

You should see `assetPromptDisabled` set to true. Set it to false and restart VS Code. Now you'll get the prompt again.

Comment: This is great, thank you. A slightly faster way to find this setting is to simply enter `assetPromptDisabled` into the filter on the Application tab.

Comment: this is exactly what I'm here for. I was hoping "don't ask again" meant "yes; don't ask again", then discovered it means "no; don't ask again"

Answer (score 0):

April 2023, VSCode version 1.77.0

I didn't find the `assetPromptDisabled` flag in the developer console as @Llewey wrote. But during my searches, I found another way to reset this flag:

In the `%APPDATA%\Code\User\workspaceStorage` directory we have folders with coded workspaces names.
For each folder that we open in VSCode, a subfolder is created in the `workspaceStorage` folder.
Inside each subfolder is the file `state.vscdb`. This file is in SQLite format. If you look at the contents of this file, you can find a table `ItemTable` in which you can see the following row:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| ms-dotnettools.csharp | {"lastSolutionPathOrFolder":"\\path\\to\\your\\project", "assetPromptDisabled":true} |

And here we have two options, either use any SQLite editor to delete this row (leaving the rest of the settings intact), or delete the entire folder from the `workspaceStorage` folder.

If anyone has information on how to do this from the VSCode settings, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried here to uninstall all the extensions related to C# that I had in VsCode (But I took notes to avoid not installing some of them back), when I reinstalled them the prompt reappeared. I think this can be the solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).